# Cannot get total of required 100 in Scipy linear programming

Tags: python, linear-programming, scipy-optimize

I am trying to solve  a optimization problem, When I use too simple data sets, I get accurate results and the sum of res.x sums up to 100, which I want, but when I use my original data, the res.x gives variables that either are under 1 or negative values, second they dont sum up to 100.

The simpler version which works is this:

```
from scipy.optimize import linprog
# sample data
c = [90, 190]
A = [[12, 50], [4.4, 1.2]]
b = [22, 3.6]
res = linprog(c, A_eq=A, b_eq=b)
res.x
# Output array([0.74708171, 0.26070039])
```

This example works fine, but as I will use more realistic values, the problem will not solve correctly.

```
# sample data
# costs
c = [15, 16, 22, 90]
A = [
    # cp
      [8, 8, 12, 41], 
    # me
      [3.4, 3.5, 3.3, 3.5]
    #  can further take dm as well
]
b = [15, 2.0]
x0_bounds = (0, 50)
x1_bounds = (0, 25)
x2_bounds = (0, 10)
x3_bounds = (0, 3)
bounds=[x0_bounds, x1_bounds, x2_bounds, x3_bounds]

res = linprog(c, A_ub=A, b_ub=b, bounds=bounds)
res.x
# Output:
# array([8.51258834e-15, 4.70244892e-14, 8.70913453e-14, 2.34489024e-14])
```

I also tried to get help from a similar problem, but reproducing same code from this repo also didnt help. https://github.com/thotasu/scipy.optimize.linprog/blob/master/whiskas.ipynb

Comment: There's no constraint that enforces that x sums up to 100 in both of your examples. Why do you expect a solution that fulfils this constraint then?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Later I realized I have to put the sum as 100 also in the form of a constraint, like `x1 + x2 = 100`, so I had to add another equation.

```
c = [90, 190]
A = [[12, 50], [4.4, 1.2], [1, 1]]
b = [22, 3.6, 100]
```